# Android Map API v2 not showing Map on some Devices

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-api-2, mapfragment

I am developing an Android application showing a map.

I'm using a MapFragment in which I display my map.
I obtained an API Key and added all the needed permissions to my manifest.

**So far so good, everything works fine when debugging the app on my HTC One S on Android 4.1.2 the map shows including controls and everything else.**

**When I debug the same application on my Galaxy S4 running Android 4.2.2, the map stays blank and only controls show.**

Internet connection is definitely available.

- Why is that the case?
- Is there any difference between android 4.1 and 4.2 concerning the v2 Map API?
- Is there any difference between Samsung and HTC concerning the issue?
- Do I need a new key for some devices?

The "error message" I get on the Galaxy S4 is **"Failed to load map. Could not contact google services."**

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="myobtainedkey" />
```

Again: Everything works fine on my HTC One S, I'm looking for the reason why the map is not loading on the S4?

Things I already tried:

- uninstall the app and reinstall it again
- update / reinstall google play services
- use wifi only / use data connection only
- restart the device
- clean the project

Comment: Uninstall the app and try again.

Comment: I also tried uninstalling, still no change.

Comment: I have a question concerning the package-name for the permissions. Should I use the one that is listed in my manifest?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I have it as well.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it a solution, but I managed to get the map displayed after signing the apk.
So the debug apk doesn't show the map on Galaxy S4, but when I sign the apk and install it on the S4, the map shows up. I'm still curious why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea why, but just yesterday it started to work.
I made no changes to the application at all.

**Probably it was just a network issue or google made some kind of upate on their google-services so that it now works.**

Answer (score 2):

Try installing/updating google services on your Galaxy S4.

Comment: I already had that issue where a button showed up in the map where I could update the services, which I did.
Now the update button is gone and instead the map just remains blank.

Answer (score 1):

Please check date and time on your device. It seems like map is taking time stamp from the device. Map will only load if current time and device times are same